# Is it too soon to keg if im storing for a few weeks?

Tags: dry-hop, ipa, primary-fermentation

I just dry hopped an IPA i brewed on July 30th. I plan on kegging it next Wednesday, exactly one week from today. The Beer has had a full 10 days of primary fermentation so far and is only going to finsish around 6%. I am going to keg it next wednesday and store it til sep 3rd for my week at the beach.

Am I correct in thinking that the fermentation will CERTAINLY be 100% done by then, and if i keg it and gas it to store it, that it'll be alright?

I plan on throwing another Oz of Citra in a bag and dropping it in the keg a couple days before i tap it just to boost the aroma. I just want to make sure im not jumping the gun and missing some crucial final touches.

Comment: I see this post is quite old, but I'm curious why you were worried about fermentation being complete if you were kegging it. I'm new to kegging so forgive me if I'm missing something, but I would think that _even if_  fermentation was partially incomplete not only would the keg be able to withstand the pressure, but you would have a naturally carbonated beer inside the keg. I would also think that shouldn't effect you adding hops before tapping.

Answer (score 1):

You really won't know where it will finish until it holds SG for a couple days.

But for the sake of your situation I would do as you plan, but skip the hop in the keg and store it at serving temp.

Comment: yeah i decided to wait until next friday to give it 2 solid extra days and skip the keg hop. I am going to have to probably store it at 65-70 degrees though. is that an issue?

Comment: @PatrickTyler you may get some secondary fermentation, making a cloudy beer, other than that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Cornelius keg (or Corny keg), and you're worried about fermentation not being complete, you could grab a keg lid with an air lock fitting and leave that on for a little longer before carbonating the keg.  Obviously switch to the standard lid before adding CO2.

[Cornelius Keg Lid for Secondary Fermenter for sale @ Hombrewing.org](http://www.homebrewing.org/Cornelius-Keg-Lid-for-Secondary-Fermenter_p_999.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=shopping&gclid=CI_J3Izq4tACFQUQaQodWg4PBQ)

Answer (score 0):

Storing at room Temp will not harm your beer as long as the fermentation has fininshed, use a clearing agent 2 days before kegging, gas to purge the oxygen out, then the longer it is stored at room temp the better it gets.